# how to attach existing images(image field) to node in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, media

I use the following code to upload images

```
$node  = node_load($nid); 
$file  = (object) array(
  'uid' => $v['uid'],//@todo from query
  'uri' => 'public://'.$v['filename'],//@todo from query
  'filemime' => $v['filemime'],//@todo from query
  'status'   => $v['status'],//@todo from query
  'fid' => $v['fid'],
  'filesize' => $v['filesize'],
  'timestamp' => $v['timestamp'],
  'type' =>'image',
  'metadata' => array('height' =>1200,'width'=>1099),
  'height' => 1200,
  'width'  => 1099,
);
$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $file;
node_save($node);
```

This does not work, I am not able to figure out the error in the code which prevents from image upload

Comment: Where is the `$v` coming from?

Comment: its coming from foreach loop @NoSssweat

Comment: Hi @NoSssweat, I have a d6 database table content_field_image from where I am fetching the data and I need to place it here in the above code,  advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: D6 , no comment, D6 is before my time.

Comment: No but , can u provide me an example of how to upload image programmatically provided I have an image url on the public path in D7 @NoSssweat

Answer (score 1):

> can u provide me an example of how to upload image programmatically
>   provided I have an image url on the public path in D7

This should do the trick

```
$node  = node_load($nid);     
$image = file_get_contents('public://images/folder_name/image_name.jpg');
$file  = file_save_data($image, 'public://images/folder_name/image_name.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'] = $file->fid;
node_save($node);
```